# Why is this simple (nested) if statment not working?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm looking to achieve the following:

If it's Saturday or Sunday, show the we're closed page.
If it's not Saturday or Sunday: 
.If it is outside of working hours (not between 9am and 12pm), show the we're closed page.
.If it is within working hours, show the we're open page.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<TITLE>Golborne Patient Booking Portal </TITLE>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function ampmRedirect() {   

    var currentTime = new Date();
    var currentHour = currentTime.getHours();
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay();
    
    if (n == 0) || (n == 6){                                                    // if Saturday or Sunday
        window.location.href = "closed.html";                                   // we are closed
        } else {                                                                // if it is any other day
            if ((currentHour < 8) || (currentHour > 11)) {                      // if outside of working hours (8am to noon)
                window.location.href = "closed.html";                           // we are closed
            } else {                                                            // anything else (not weekday or within the times)
                window.location.href = "open.html";    // we are open
            }
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="ampmRedirect()">
</body>
</html>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need parenthesis around your if statement, like you have on your inner if statement.

Comment: An `if` statement requires `( )` around the **entire** conditional expression. Your code has a syntax error therefore that the browser would report in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the missing parenthese around the condition expression, you could take a single check with day and time and assign either a closing page or another target.

```js
function ampmRedirect() {
    var date = new Date(),
        time = date.getHours(),
        day = date.getDay();

    window.location.href = day === 0 || day === 6 || time < 8 || time > 11
        ? "closed.html"
        : "https://golborne.abtrace-cloud.com";
}
```

```html
<body onload="ampmRedirect()">
```